# Does Mathematica compute free-form-input on Wolfram servers?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, free-form-input, applicationserver

I've just started to use *Mathematica* and I'm using the free-form input a lot. The computation time for simple problems seems to take a lot of time and my CPU isn't really used at all. I first thought that the f-f-input would be transferred to a Wolfram server, converted into the *Mathematica* programming language and computed on my PC. Is that really the case? I didn't find anything about this on the *Mathematica* website and I'd like to know how that and Wolfram Alpha-queries in *Mathematica* 9 works.

Comment: This is mentioned, in typical WRI documentation style, in the following pages: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/free-form-linguistic-input/ and http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/WolframAlphaIntegration.html

Comment: @rm-rf Nothing I've asked is answered on those two pages

Comment: qwertz, welcome to [Mathematica.SE].

Comment: thank you, glad I found you guys.